# How to perform Realm count query

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, realm

How can I do a count query on Realm?

for example this is my model

```
class Dog: Object {
  dynamic var name = ""
}
class Person: Object {
  dynamic var name = ""

  let dogs = List<Dog>()
}
```

I want to fetch all persons with at least one dog
something like

```
Realm().objects(Person).filter("dogs.@count > 0")
```

but @count isn't supported as i understand

Comment: Update: it's now supported!  Exciting!  Your query `filter("dogs.@count > 0")` will work from version 0.96.0.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Realm still does not support `.@count` query. You can work around that you modify the `Person` model to have a `count` property. Then you update the `count` property when you append a dog object to the `dogs` array.

This feature request is tracked by Issue #1166 https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1166

#### Update

Realm supports `@count` and other collection queries from v0.96.

Comment: Just to save myself clicking through next time…the issue's closed. `@count` is now supported.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for the new aggregate expressions (`@count`, `@min`, `@max`, `@sum`, `@avg`) for `Results` and `List` looks like this:

```
realm.objects(Person.self).filter("dogs.@count > 0")
```