# Select Count in Realm for Android

Tags: java, android, sql, count, realm

I saw some answers about this problem for iOS [(here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31906563/how-to-perform-realm-count-query), but none for Android.

Let's say I have 2 columns A and B and I want the distincts couples of A and B and the count of the couple. I then want to filter my query when the count is <60.

```
A|B
1|1
1|1
1|1
2|1
2|1
2|1
1|2
1|2
1|2
1|2
```

In pure SQL, I used the query :

```
SELECT A,B, COUNT(A) FROM myTable GROUP BY A,B
```

Which give me something like [(1,1,3), (2,1,3), (1,2,4)]

**How can I do so with Realm in Android ?**

Comment: Try to provide ios answer ref so someone look out and help from it for android.

Comment: thx, it is in the link on the first line.

Comment: I don't think you can project a single column, or two single columns; because you can only get the whole object

Answer (score -1):

Currently it is not possible to do in a single statement. You will have to do something like:

```
RealmResults<MyObject> myObjects = realm.where(MyObject.class).distinct("A", "B");
for (MyObject myObject : myObjects) {
    long count = realm.where(MyObject.class).equalsTo("A", myObject.getA()).equalsTo("B", myObject.getB()).count();
    // use getA(), getB(), and count
}
```